# Prevent custom post type from showing up in custom menus

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, metabox

How do I do that?

Any custom post type I register shows up as a meta box on the menu page...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple, when registering the Custom Post Type use:

```
register_post_type( 'post_type_name', array (
...
'show_in_nav_menus' => FALSE
...
) );
```

Comment: I feel so stupid now :(

Comment: Don't! I spent 4 hours debugging my cpt meta box callback...turns out there was a space in the array name :(